# android lollipop webrtc webview app

Tags: android, webview, webrtc

He at all. I try to test my app based on lollipop API 22 devices.

As a test I make a webview and try to connect to url "https://appr.tc/r/xxxxx".

As result in my webview I can see my front camera preview, the appr server messages (button named joint .... etc.) .. but if try to establish a RTC peer chat I obtain these error:

> the page at https://appr.tc says: cannot create rtcpeerconnection:
>   undefined is not a function

**I have these row on .grandle ...**

```
implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.+'
```

**I have these manifest permission ...**

```html
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.webkit.PermissionRequest" />

    <meta-data android:name="android.webkit.WebView.MetricsOptOut"
        android:value="true" />
    <meta-data android:name="android.webkit.WebView.EnableSafeBrowsing"
        android:value="true" />
```

**and I have these java code for implement webview chrome ...**

```js
public class CameraViewFrag extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "CameraViewFrag";
    private WebView mWebView;
    private String url = "https://appr.tc/r/658450307";
    private Button goOnButton;



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera_view,container,false);

        goOnButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.gotoButton);
        mWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            webSettings.setSafeBrowsingEnabled(true);
        }

        goOnButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
                mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
                mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
                mWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
                mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
                mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
                mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
                mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
                mWebView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
                //carichiamo finalmete la url
                mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
                    // Need to accept permissions to use the camera
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                request.grant(request.getResources());
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
                mWebView.loadUrl(url);
            }
        });







        return view;
    }
}
```

the cose is insight a fragment .....

I do not see my mistake and I have not found an answer to this kind of error until now on stack neither on google....

sorry ... I add the interesting part of logcat:

```html
01-16 12:00:36.627 12598-12598/com.example.bleahkthe.test I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(5590)] "4.864: Opening signaling channel.", source: https://appr.tc/js/apprtc.debug.js (5590)
01-16 12:00:37.007 12598-12598/com.example.bleahkthe.test I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(5590)] "5.274: Joined the room.", source: https://appr.tc/js/apprtc.debug.js (5590)
01-16 12:00:37.169 12598-12598/com.example.bleahkthe.test I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(5590)] "5.444: Signaling channel opened.", source: https://appr.tc/js/apprtc.debug.js (5590)
01-16 12:00:37.169 12598-12598/com.example.bleahkthe.test I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(5590)] "5.445: Registering signaling channel.", source: https://appr.tc/js/apprtc.debug.js (5590)
01-16 12:00:37.171 12598-12598/com.example.bleahkthe.test I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(5590)] "5.445: Signaling channel registered.", source: https://appr.tc/js/apprtc.debug.js (5590)
01-16 12:00:37.172 12598-12598/com.example.bleahkthe.test I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(5590)] "5.450: Starting signaling.", source: https://appr.tc/js/apprtc.debug.js (5590)
01-16 12:00:37.173 12598-12598/com.example.bleahkthe.test I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(5590)] "5.455: Creating RTCPeerConnnection with:
                                                                                 config: '{"rtcpMuxPolicy":"require","bundlePolicy":"max-bundle","iceServers":[{"urls":["turn:74.125.143.127:19305?transport=udp","turn:[2607:f8b0:400d:c09::7f]:19305?transport=udp","turn:74.125.143.127:443?transport=tcp","turn:[2607:f8b0:400d:c09::7f]:443?transport=tcp"],"username":"CNDZ/NIFEgbJSf4StDgYzc/s6OMTIICjBQ","credential":"P6ssOSIPA2wBBQMHXiDa9BEsJUI="},{"urls":["stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"]}]}';
                                                                                 constraints: '{"optional":[]}'.", source: https://appr.tc/js/apprtc.debug.js (5590)
01-16 12:00:37.204 12598-12598/com.example.bleahkthe.test I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(5590)] "5.487: Created PeerConnectionClient", source: https://appr.tc/js/apprtc.debug.js (5590)
01-16 12:00:37.207 12598-12598/com.example.bleahkthe.test I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(5590)] "5.491: Adding local stream.", source: https://appr.tc/js/apprtc.debug.js (5590)
01-16 12:00:37.214 12598-12598/com.example.bleahkthe.test I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(5590)] "5.499: Create PeerConnection exception: TypeError: undefined is not a function", source: https://appr.tc/js/apprtc.debug.js (5590)
01-16 12:00:37.296 12598-12615/com.example.bleahkthe.test D/ufoEGL: Pixel Format : GGL_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBA_8888
01-16 12:00:39.710 12598-12615/com.example.bleahkthe.test D/ufoEGL: Surface destroy: ANDROID_NATIVE_WINDOW_MAGIC
01-16 12:00:39.714 12598-12615/com.example.bleahkthe.test D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xce92f800 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xde6cc030
01-16 12:00:46.322 12598-12615/com.example.bleahkthe.test D/ufoEGL: Pixel Format : GGL_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBA_8888
01-16 12:00:48.255 12598-12598/com.example.bleahkthe.test I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 47570(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 4(61KB) LOS objects, 40% free, 6MB/10MB, paused 695us total 54.479ms
01-16 12:00:48.260 12598-12598/com.example.bleahkthe.test I/art: System.exit called, status: 0
01-16 12:00:48.262 12598-12598/com.example.bleahkthe.test I/AndroidRuntime: VM exiting with result code 0, cleanup skipped.
```

regards
bkt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the webview takes property of the default browser and if the default one is not chrome then it is unsupported. Ask for browsers to open the url. and choose chrome to make the webrtc call.

Comment: in these lollipop devices is not possible to install chrome ... so how can use your suggest? ... I know I can "unblock" the device and make an installation. But is not mi preferred choice because the warranty of device.

Comment: call  mWebView.loadUrl(url); first (using default browser with mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());) and set chrome after 
                mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()    not solve the situation

Comment: Like this it won't work in webview. You need the native implementation of webrtc. https://webrtc.org/native-code/android/

Comment: ok ...  ok I understood I was hoping not ..... so my test will be a little longer to achieve. Thank you.